# AzureRM equivalent of Get-AzureWebSiteLog -Tail

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm desperate to find an equivalent of Get-AzureWebSiteLog -Tail (Log Stream) in any technology:

- Get-AzureWebSiteLog requires to connect with Add-AzureAccount which
  needs to be at least co-admin of the full subscription which is a no
  go
- Azure RM doesn't seem to provide an equivalent

switching to azure cli, of course, doesn't change anything about the initial problem (permissions).

Comment: Based on my knowledge, `Get-AzureWebSiteLog` could use in ARM mode, you could refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log#a-namestreamlogsa-how-to-stream-logs). Also, you could check stream log on Azure portal, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-streaming-logs-and-console).

Comment: I see no reference (and I tried) on how "linking" ARM authentication for ASM cmdlet. Am I missing something ? I might fall back to another approach using curl.exe https://xxxx.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/logstream. It's not exactly what I was trying to achieve first but it's acceptable.

Comment: I also did not find anything about that command, but now this exists `Get-AzureRmLog `